# Wordpress - TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pricing increase/decrease slider on my homepage. But the slider has suddenly stopped displaying. When I look into the console I am getting these error.

```
TypeError: $(...).swiper is not a function
TypeError: jQuery(...).slider is not a function
```

I also have jQuery and UI libraries installed.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: this error is more related to javascript and jquery, not wordpress and php

Comment: These seem to be functions that come from a jQuery plugin. Are you loading any of these?